# How to recognize URL's in listview in android?

Tags: android

I am parsing a JSON and getting back text in the form of an arraylist, this arraylist is used to show the text in a listview. I am able to get the text, but is there any way to recognize the urls in the text and make them clickable so that they can be used to follow the links?
Can anyone suggest a method to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to make a adapter and a textItem for the different strings.
use something like 
myTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml("

"+yourContents+"

"));
this should make the links clickable. I hope this wirks, of not than change the textView with a webView and do more research and read how to add contents to the webview and change the back ground so will look like textView. I know this is possible I have done it.

Answer (score 1):

Just call `setOnItemClickListener` on your ListView, and then override `onItemClick`.

Edit - use something like this:

```
listView.setClickable(true);
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

  @Override
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {

     String url = listView.getItemAtPosition(position);

     //open url
     startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it I added a textview in the list and for a textview there is a property called autolink which recognizes the links and also can be made clickable